# ASP.Net C# Active Directory: Inherited an application with thread.sleep() after each DirectoryEntry.MoveTo() calls

Tags: c#, active-directory

So I'm working on this application that was developed by other people that are not involved with the project anymore.  As stated in the title there are a few thread.sleep() calls that have me scratching my head.  I have no experience working with AD.

The worst offender is the following one with a 50 second sleep in a class that inherits `Principle`.

```
public class Computer:ComputerPrinciple
{
    ...
    public void MoveToOu(string ou)
    {
        var userObject = (DirectoryEntry)GetUnderlyingObject();
        var newParentOu = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ou);

        userObject.MoveTo(newParentOu);

        Thread.Sleep(50000);
        userObject.Close();
        newParentOu.Close();
    }
    ...
}
```

There is nothing that explains the reason but I suspect it was an issue with the page refreshing before the changes were fully committed (?). One thing I'm pretty sure of is that `Thread.Sleep(50000)` is not the correct solution to whatever problem they we're having.

I'd like to hear from people who have experience with this if there is indeed some sort of issue that this would "fix" and what would be the incorporate solution.

Also I'm thinking I should use the "using" directive but I'm wondering about disposing the `UnderlyingObject` or even just closing it because this code is called from something like this where computer is the principle in witch the move code is

```
  computer.UpdateComputerDescription(collection);
  computer.UpdateComputerOu(collection);   <--- offending MoveToOu method is called in here
  computer.UpdateComputerIsActivedProperty(collection);
  computer.Save();
```

Would closing or disposing of the `underlyingObject` have a side effect on the methods after that call?

Any input would be welcome.

Comment: as far as I can see, MoveToOu only takes a string parameter and does not use `collection` at all? --> so whatever you create and dispose inside `MoveToOu` would not impact objects in calling code.

Comment: @dlatikay I didnt post the code in UpdatecomputerOu but there is something in there that extract the OU and will call the MoveToOu method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of `Thread.Sleep` is likely a workaround for not calling `CommitChanges`.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f369wf4z(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If UsePropertyCache is true, call the CommitChanges method on the new object to make the move permanent

It looks like they were waiting for the cache to flush using an empirical delay.

Second, wrapping any `IDisposable` **you create** inside `MoveToOu` in `using` will not break anything. It is the correct way to go. Objects used, but not created, inside `MoveToOu` scope should not be disposed here, but rather be left to the container class dispose mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had read that but it didnt really click and I wasnt sure it was leading me down a wrong pat.  I just ran a test and UsePropertyCache is indeed true.     And about the using, just to clarify does this (DirectoryEntry)myPrinciple.GetUnderlyingObject() create a new object?